# Create a gke pod from a google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to create a google cloud function to create pods on my gke cluster. I  use the [python kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to create them (I don't know if there is a better way to achive this).

Normally I would use the command: `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster_name --region=cluster_region` but cloud sdk is not installed in the cloud function environment.

I've read the python api documentation and I found that it is possible to pass the path to the kubeconfig file, but I didn't found how to create that file

Comment: Maybe you can store the credentials in secret manager and pull them from the CF when needed

Comment: @FerreginaPelona The gke cluster credentials? I've tried to create the kubeconfig file, but I dindn't found how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get credential does nothing special:

- Check if the cluster exists
- Check if you have the permission on the cluster
- Create the Kube config file with your access token.

That's all.

Now, when you use the kubectl command, the access token is used and put in the `Authorization: Bearer` header and perform an API call to Kubernetes control plane.

Therefore, if you want to reach directly the control plane from your Cloud Functions with an API call, simply the Cloud Functions access token in the security header and that's all!

Comment: How can I get the kube config file without gcloud? I didn't found any way to do that. Otherwise, it is needed to make an API call to the control plane of my cluster? How can I make the API call from my cloud function?

Comment: How will you call your kubernetes cluster? With Kubectl or with API request?

Comment: With the python kubernetes API client

Comment: So, as I said, you don't need the KubeConfig file, you only need an Access Token to call the control plane API